# What do following options mean in /boot/config.txt?

Tags: overclocking

I have gone through many overclocking tutorials on the web. I have seen fewparticular lines in `config.txt`,

`sdram_schmoo=0x02000020`
`isp_freq=0`
`avoid_pwm_pll=1`
`avoid_safe_mode=1`

Can anyone please tell me their meanings?

Please provide detailed answer.